# real-time update of table with data coming from websocket using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, real-time

I need to update a table in real-time with data coming from the web socket.

What I do now is every time I get data on the socket I append it to a string and create a double dimensional array which is used to display the table using ng-repeat.

The performance using this approach is quite slow. Besides this approach assumes that I am getting the message in sequence, however I do not get the data in the correct sequence.

Would it be better to format the data as html or json and send it over web socket or sending the raw data is better?

What would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are recreating the two dimensional array each time from this string, a faster way would be to just push new data onto the array instead.

Sending the data as HTML is not the way to go, but formatting the data as JSON on the server will almost certainly help speed things up on the client side. Sending small pieces of data and then incrementally appending them to your array on the client, then re-sorting the data (if needed) will likely be faster.

Another option would be to use something like [Underscore.js's throttle function](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) to limit the number of times you cause a digest cycle in AngularJS. You could also grab [just throttle](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L621) if you don't want to include all of underscore into your project.

Comment: thanks for the response, I have formatted the data as JSON on the server and am sending it to the client now.

Comment: However I have 2 types of data to be displayed in 2 different tables, would I have to parse the JSON string or is there any other method to differentiate the data? Also I tried using the directive for jquery plugin datatables however I get an error Object [[object HTMLTableCellElement], [object HTMLTableCellElement]] has no method 'each' at the line
explicitColumns.push($(elem).text()); after
element.find('th').each(function (index, elem) { I have included DataTables-1.9.4, could that be a problem?